# Windows phone textBox issue

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I am writing a WP8 app, and I want to add one particular functionality - there is textBlock on a page that may contain text of different length. I want to add some control, that would allow writing down letters of the text separately. My first idea was to create GridView with textBoxes, however there is no such control as GridView in WP8 and apart from that, I don't think that is the best sollution.  I can't really think of any way how to do this, so I am asking You for help - help me please, 'cause I'm really out of ideas. It should look sth like this:

[image]

I am sorry if my question is unclear - I am just not sure how to express my idea.

Thank You in advance for Your help! :)

Comment: Did I understood that right: You need a few textboxes, each of these just for one character?

Comment: On GUIs when designing and asking for help maybe you should post a mockup or prototype using something like Pencil? http://pencil.evolus.vn/

Comment: Malte, yes, that's right, but the thing is that the number of textBoxes is not const, it may vary.

Comment: AthomSfere, ok, i'll do it - btw thanks for the link, that's a very usefull program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s = "stackoverflow"; // or = mytextblock.Text; in your example.
foreach (char c in s)
{
    //create a new textbox
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    //you should make some changes to the textbox here (size, maxlength, name, etc.)
    //add the textbox to your stackpanel
    mystackpanel.Children.Add(tb);
}
```

and something like the following in your XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="mystackpanel"/>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, just one question - e.g if I need to create 15 textboxes, I would need to put them in 3 rows - is that possible to achieve? Or it will automatically sort them in 3 rows? I'll try it myself  - I hope it will work

Comment: Using a WrapPanel instead of the StackPanel should work in this case.